# dlib's scan_fhog_pyramid : set max_pyramid_levels

Tags: c++, dlib

I am using an object detector that has the following type:

`dlib::object_detector<dlib::scan_fhog_pyramid<dlib::pyramid_down<2>>>`

My code is like this :

```
dlib::object_detector<dlib::scan_fhog_pyramid<dlib::pyramid_down<2>>> d;   
dlib::deserialize(svm_path) >> d;
d.get_scanner().set_max_pyramid_levels(max_levels);
```

So basically what i'm doing is defining an object detector. Deserializing an already trained `svm` into this object detector. And in the last line, I'm trying to configure the detector by changing the number of levels of the hog pyramid.

The last line does not compile as `get_scanner()` returns `const image_scanner_type &`. So changing `max_pyramid_levels` won't work. I would like to know if there is a way to change that in order to scan less images (ie. The pyramid will have less images).

My goal is to enhance the performance of the detector and in my case I'm sure that only few image scales in the pyramid are needed.

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct new object detector with new image scanner:

```
typedef dlib::scan_fhog_pyramid<dlib::pyramid_down<2> > image_scanner_type;
typedef dlib::object_detector<image_scanner_type> detector_type;
detector_type d;   
dlib::deserialize(svm_path) >> d;
image_scanner_type new_scanner;
new_scanner.copy_configuration(d.get_scanner());
new_scanner.set_max_pyramid_levels(1);
detector_type new_d(new_scanner, d.get_overlap_tester(), d.get_w());
```

Or use const_cast.

Comment: This is a wondeful answer ! Exactly what I wanted ! Thank you @Evgeniy, I didn't know that the function copy_configuration existed. I must have missed it while reading the documentation. One last question : do you kno if changing max_pyramid_levels would affect the detector's precision ? I'm pretty sure that the performance will be better, but not sure about the precision.

Comment: Yes, the precision will be affected. As object position precision, as the count of detections. You will lose some of possible objects. The idea of pyramid is to find objects of deifferent scale. If the scale of objects does not change much - about +20% (6/5) is normal scale change that one detector can handle in one pyramid level. Also you can try training some custom detector that will work good on multiple scales as-is without pyramid. I have successfully trained such ones. Also make sure that all optimizations like AVX are ON

Comment: I see.  The documentation says that the default max_pyramid_levels is 1000. Does this mean that the function deserialize will put this value by default in my detector ? Or that the value depends on the training itself (it is stored somewhere in the svm file)? I'm afraid that if I change max_pyramid_levels, this would affect my detector.

Comment: Yes, this value is stored in SVM and deserialized and as i know, it is not changed in training process. Only testing will show you how much your detector is affected. max_pyramid_levels = 1 will make your detector work 2-3x faster (if your images are large), but it will work only in one scale. In some situations it is acceptable. Just try it and you will see