# Dlib. How solve the optimization constraints to be on real time ? Idea of landmarks convergence?

Tags: c++, optimization, dlib

I wanted to use dlib library to detect face landmarks in real time. 
The algorithm is based by the paper: One Millisecond Face Alignment with an Ensemble of Regression Trees by Vahid Kazemi and Josephine Sullivan

I use the existing library : dlib and it is quite slow. I read how to do it quickly on http://dlib.net/faq.html, but it is not possible on my computer, because I do not have the option to optimize until SSE4 or AVX. Finally, I use SSE2.
So I have the following questions :

-It is possible to use in mobile/web application library dlib in order that it works in real time ? I am not familar with optimization settings and so on, that is why it is interesting how much restrictions there are.

-It is possible to use in my computer without optimisation SSE4 in order that it works in real time ?

-This file shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat weights 95 Mb. I need just face+landmark detection, does this file contain redundant information according to my needs?

-One algorithm question : The convergence of points(landmarks) depends on the bounding box of face detection, could smb explain, how it is done ? We fit points of mean face inside bounding box and then we are looking for each landmark optimal position in its neighborhood ? How much this neighborhood ?

Thanks to any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-It is possible to use in mobile/web application library dlib in order that it works in real time ? I am not familar with optimization settings and so on, that is why it is interesting how much restrictions there are.

-It is possible to use in my computer without optimisation SSE4 in order that it works in real time ?
```

Face landmark detection has two steps: face detection and face landmark detection on this face. And the most CPU-consuming part is first step - detect face (running simple_object_detector), and only this part has any profit from usage AVX/SSE

Why is it slow - face detection is drained for face size from 80x80 pixels and larger, and if you will put some high-resolution image into detector, it will spend much time on sliding window in different scales. Most situations need to have 1-3 faces on the same frame, while resolution of modern mobile cameras are quite high.

So I recommend you to reduce the image size used for face detection - downscale it and crop it by some region of interest. This will make you largest possible performance optimization.

The next possible step is to make face detector not to run in different scales, but may be on 1-2 iterations. Take a look at this question - it has this problem described ([dlib's scan_fhog_pyramid : set max_pyramid_levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529251/dlibs-scan-fhog-pyramid-set-max-pyramid-levels))

```
-This file shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat weights 95 Mb. I need just face+landmark detection, does this file contain redundant information according to my needs?
```

This file has only data model for 68 face landmarks trained on iBug dataset. It does not have face detection model inside. Face detection model ships in dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h file

Yes, this file is quite big, but this is the price of its quality. You can train some new face landmark detection model (described in http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html example) witl less landmark points or with less quality - this can make you much smaller file

```
-One algorithm question...
```

To answer it - please consider reading original (http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Kazemi_One_Millisecond_Face_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf) and dlib/image_processing/shape_predictor.h source code

Shortely - after face is detected (bounding box found), shape predictor searches some features (image pixels values) at pre-trained positions relatively for face bounding box. Depending on feature values shape_predictor changes *mean face shape* into new face shape (prediceted one), and this process is made iteratively for each trained regression tree inside shape predictor model

Comment: Thanks. Just one question. If I use different face detector algorithm, how much time do you think will take only points convergence given bounding box (it can be in real time without optimization settings) ?
I asked about the algorithm question because if I use different face detector, it can give imperfection on the bounding box, than if the points are looking in the neighborhood of the points of mean shape, it could not well convergence. (Actually I am also Russian =))

Comment: yes, it will work at real time, i think 1-2 msec per face. and yes, you will loose some convergence, because the size and position of face bounding box affects the precision of shape prediction. but you can train one new shape_predictor with using your detector as source for bounding boxes. it takes less than one day of training and you will need 32+ GB RAM. I even tried to use simple 16x16 fixed size box with different real face size and position and it trained well